# Sort a substring using STL

Tags: c++, string, stl

Is there any way to sort a substring using STL?

I know I can do this.

```
std::string word="dcba";
std::sort(word.begin(), word.end());
```

But how do I obtain iterators for arbitrary indices?

Eg- If I wanted to sort from indices 2 to 4, "dcab"

Edit - This was needed for a function to generate the next lexicographical sequence from a given string.

```
bool nextLex(string s) {
    for(int i=s.length()-1;i>=0;i--) {
        for(int j=i-1;j>=0;j--) {
            if(s[j]<s[i]) {
                swap(s[i],s[j]);
                sort(s.begin()+j,s.end());
                cout<<s<<endl;
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
return false;
}
```

Comment: word.begin()+2, word.begin()+4. Don't forget to check size

Comment: You may look at `std::next_permutation` for your next lexicographical sequence. [Demo](https://ideone.com/M2Z5MT)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::string` uses random-access iterators, so you can simply add the indexes to the `begin` iterator:

```
std::string word="dcba";
std::sort(word.begin()+2, word.begin()+4);
```

Alternatively, you can use `std::advance()`:

```
std::string word="dcba";

std::string::iterator start = word.begin();
std::advance(start, 2);

std::string::iterator end = start;
std::advance(end, 2);

std::sort(start, end);
```

Alternatively, you can use `std::next()` (C++11 and later):

```
std::string word="dcba";
std::sort(std::next(word.begin(), 2), std::next(word.begin(), 4));
```

Or:

```
std::string word="dcba";
auto start = std::next(word.begin(), 2);
std::sort(start, std::next(start, 2));
```

Comment: Thanks! This sees to works. Although my code still doesn't seem to be doing what it should. I have edited the original question, would you mind taking a look at it, please?